# color in Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, expression-manipulation

I've created a movie of my diagram. And I want to make it more colorful. When my code runs, a line moves in the figure. I want the region below the line black as movie runs. Can anyone help me? 
The code is

```
R = 17;
l = 1.7;
ro = 0.05;
pe = 22;
dd = 7.5 10^-14;
dc = 2 10^-10;
Manipulate[ContourPlot[(3.8/R)^4  (1 + 2 (1 + delta) pe^2) - (3.8 /R)^2 8 
3.14 ro (t + x pe (1 + delta)) == 0, {t, 0, 20}, {x, 0, 3}], {{delta, .3}, 
0, .4}]
```

Comment: It was an example. I also want to plot variable 'pe' versus x and solving this  equation is not very easy for it. Or maybe in other examples I want to plot some something that I can not find the solution myself.

Comment: I mean I want to color the eq., when it is below zero, but I cannot use <= because it doesn't work!

Comment: Thank yo, You are right. One more question: Do you know how can I retain region which movie starts from in someother color??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Example

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x y], {y, 0, 3}, Filling -> Bottom],
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}
 ]
```

### Output

[image: Sin]

### Reference

[Filling](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html)

Comment: Ok, OP agrees with you so that;s all :)